# Can I create an abstract enum in TypeScript? (use in an interface and provide specific ones per each implementing class)

Tags: typescript

Consider the following case:

- there's several classes (like `class Wizard`, `class Bard`, `class Knight`)
- each implementing an interface (`interface ICharacter`)
- each character should have a mascot which is supposed to be specified in the `constructor`, but each class has its own set of possible mascots, like: Wizard → "orb", "cloak", Knight → "sword", "portrait-of-a-lady-of-the-heart" etc and there are also several "common" mascots, like "pet"

Now, can I specify in `ICharacter` such type of a constructor param?

A very loose version would be:

```
constructor(
    mascot: "pet" | string
```

but the problem is obvious: this won't make any consistency check on creating an instance.

Another poor implementation would be to list all of the options in the interface, like

```
constructor(
    mascot: "pet" | "orb" | "sword" | ...
```

Again, this won't help when one tries to create a Knight with an orb as a mascot.

So I can imagine something like

```
constructor(
    mascot: "pet" | enum<string>
```

and each class should have it like

```
enum KnightMascot {
    Sword = "sword",
    ...
}

class Knight {
    constructor(
        mascot: "pet" | KnightMascot // or CommonMascot | KnightMascot
```

but it doesn't seem this can work this way (`"pet" | enum<string>` is just an invalid syntax).

Any ideas on how to implement this kind of ~enums? Or may be somebody can explain why this is not possible?

Comment: I'm not sure If I understood your problem, if it is something related with enforcing constructor types for `mascot` could something like this work for you? [Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYOwrgtgBA0iCWBzAFgFwLIEMDOBjA9qlAN4BQUFUAygO74BOAJlALxQBE2dT7ANKQF9SpUJCgB1eAC9MTLHkIlylAPL0ARqw4N1fQcNHQAwvggR8IeQSJlKUAArAibdgAcneoaUzrsqepi4RLgANjjYUEbIsoGowPQAPFaKwAAecSCMEX708CCIAHxKdgQgOWBBDAAUynYUEDjWAFxQyUQAPpGm5paNhLVQAJTEQl6h4bAIKERpGVmR0QFB8QlwSGhtRSPCIMA0k+uoVZIycn2oAHRq6oMA3JQA9A9QAKL09Ayku-tr01W-G3OF1oDEYdygTygKgA1qQgA)

Comment: @DanielRodríguezMeza yes, thanks looks very much like a solution! I'll take a closer look, but I encourage you to post this as an answer, this deserves an upvote at least (and probably will be accepted)

Answer (score 1):

You can leverage abstract classes for this problem, they are meant to extend some behavior since the `constructor` type cannot be defined through an interface, it can be through a **class**.

The use of `abstract` is actually optional, it is meant to tell that a class shouldn't be directly instantiated but instead, it should be through a child class.

Then your base class can contain generic types that can be used to control and inherit specific types and values in your child classes.

An example of this would be a class like:

```
abstract class Character<Mascot extends string> {
    constructor(
        mascot: Mascot | CommonMascot
    ){}
}
```

Here we have a `Mascot` generic that is constrained to be a **string** and at the same time the member `mascot` can be the generic or a shared predefined value (`CommonMascot`).

With all that in mind here is a complete example:

```
enum KnightMascot {
    Sword = "sword",
}

enum WizardMascot {
    Orb = "orb",
}

enum CommonMascot {
    Pet = "pet",
}

abstract class Character<Mascot extends string> {
    constructor(
        mascot: Mascot | CommonMascot
    ){}
}

class Knight extends Character<KnightMascot> {}

new Knight(WizardMascot.Orb);   // Error
new Knight(KnightMascot.Sword); // Ok
new Knight(CommonMascot.Pet);   // Ok
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYOwrgtgBA0iCWBzAFgFwLIEMDOBjA9qlAN4BQUFUAygO74BOAJlALxQBE2dT7ANKQF9SpUJCgB1eAC9MTLHkIlylAPL0ARqw4N1fQcNHQAwvggR8IeQSJlKUAArAibdgAcneoaUzrsqepi4RLgANjjYUEbIsoGowPQAPFaKwAAecSCMEX708CCIAHxKdgQgOWBBDAAUynYUEDjWAFxQyUQAPpGm5paNhLVQAJTEQl6h4bAIKERpGVmR0QFB8QlwSGhtRSPCIMA0k+uoVZIycn2oAHRq6oMA3JQA9A9QAKL09Ayku-tr01W-G3OF1oDEYdygTygKgA1l89gc-iYzBY2hdHKhwRRITDSEA)